# Asp.Net Core 2.0 login fails when Application runs in Production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I want to create a Web Service with Asp.Net Core 2.0 which enables Microsoft Account Authentication. I'm working with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x). Everything works perfectly in the local host, but fails when I publish it to my azure website.

I do get to the Microsoft login page, but once I select a user account, I get the following message:

*Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'MyApplicationId'.*

I tried changing the sign-in reply url to *mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/signin-microsoft*, same thing happened. After looking around my project, I noticed the launchSettings.json file contained several local host links, so I tried changing them to the production url, but the exact same error persisted. Could anyone be so kind to help me out?

Here is the launchSettings.json file that works correctly in my local host:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:13242/",
    "sslPort": 44372
    }
  },
 "profiles": {
 "IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44372/",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
  },
  "WebApplication13": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:13243/"
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a setting in the Microsoft Registration (of your application). In the tutorial you linked, see the section where you add/register  `Redirect Urls` -  so try adding your Azure url (or FQDN if you're using one). In other words, it may just be that the _only_ (valid) Redirect Url currently set is your localhost/dev URL.  On that note, I strongly suggest you create separate dev and production accounts for this (can't have `localhost` valid in production). Hth.

Comment: I had already tried that. That is what I meant by "I tried changing the sign-in reply url to mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/signin-microsoft, same thing happened". I also created a different account for production, nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm..odd: The error message you're receiving somehow points to some [Active Directory context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2018/01/30/azure-app-service-error-aadsts50011-the-reply-address-http-azurewebsites-netsignin-oidc-does-not-match-the-reply-addresses-configured-for-the-application/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your reply URL to the main homepage URL in both the app registration and the web.config. You shouldn't need to redirect to the sign-in url after the user has already logged in, unless you have a specific new landing page. Also make sure that the Application ID in the portal matches the Client ID in your config.

This tutorial is very helpful: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

See also: [Reply URLs Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9U1VGyztEM)

And: [Authenticate two web apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MohaxN6fsDs)

Comment: +1 awesome video. IMHO, it seems "reply url" is confusing because, as your video actually shows, its essentially the "redirect url" (?)

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the question. 

In this context they essentially serve the same purpose

Comment: From the official documentation: 

Reply URL and Redirect URI - For a web API or web application, the Reply URL is the location where Azure AD will send the authentication response, including a token if authentication was successful. For a native application, the Redirect URI is a unique identifier to which Azure AD will redirect the user-agent in an OAuth 2.0 request.

Comment: Also, it's confusing because URL is not same as URI.

"A URI can be further classified as a locator, a name, or both. The term 'Uniform Resource Locator' (URL) refers to the subset of URIs that, in addition to identifying a resource, provide a means of locating the resource by describing its primary access mechanism (e.g., its network 'location')."

Even though the meaning of that Redirect URI and Reply URL are same, Redirect URI may not be the most accurate term when it's a web app/API.